# Apache orc writer flush out memory

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, memory, orc

We are willing to create orc files with org.apache.orc.Writer. Our test were okay, till the orc file creation from a bigger database table that contained blob-s. We have tried to change the following settings but neither of them was helpful:

```
org.apache.orc.OrcFile.WriterOptions:
bufferSize()
stripeSize()
blockSize()
enforceBufferSize()
```

Orc writer is getting all the dataset and only when it is finished, writes them out, this behaviour leads to memory issues on larger datasets. Is there a way to continously populate the ORC file(flushing out from memory continuously), instead of flushing out data from memory up on closing the file writer? What is the best practice to create an orc file from datasource which contains blobs, and can't be handled only in-memory?

Any information is appreciated!

Thanks.
Tamas

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question, but I'll give my solution for any other having the same issue.

It turns out that the ORCWriter implementation checks the memory limits to flush buffer every n rows, but if your rows are big enough to consume the entire memory before a check is perfomed, then the OOM error will appear. So maybe you should try to set a smaller row count between memory checks/flushes. Default value is 5000.

```
var configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.set(OrcConf.ROWS_BETWEEN_CHECKS.getAttribute(), String.valueOf(1000));
    var options = OrcFile.writerOptions(configuration)
            .stripeSize(stripeSize)
            .setSchema(schema);
```

Documentation is here:
https://github.com/apache/orc/blob/fc6f6aee6571df6e53de5adba7cc0b2670c5df91/java/core/src/java/org/apache/orc/OrcConf.java#L165